# How to use Macaw iOS library to display svg from url

Tags: ios, swift

I need to show svg in my app. svg are available on server and can be access using url. 
I m trying to use library available at https://github.com/exyte/Macaw-Examples.
How can I use this library to display svg from a url. I can download the data as well but there is no method in the library that takes Data as parameter ?

Comment: Is there no method in `SVGParser.swift` that could help you?

Comment: no. I went through all methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `SVGParser` like so:

```swift
class MyView: MacawView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let url = ...
        let text = try! String(contentsOfFile: file.path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let node = try! SVGParser.parse(text: text)
        super.init(node: node, coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Source: https://github.com/exyte/Macaw/issues/455

Answer (score 0):

When I was working on it i used something like

```
guard let rootNode = try? SVGParser.parse(fullPath: url.path) else { return }

let macawView = MacawView(node: rootNode, frame:icon.frame)
```

There are other initialisers 
like

```
init?(node: Node, coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
init(frame: CGRect)
```

you can use.

Comment: url is server url ?. In my case svg are on server.

Comment: Did you try downloading from server and then parse the local file?

Comment: When I was working on this, my requirement was to save the file and show it from the local path. I think you are also saving it.  There are different class methods available in  SVGParser 

`parse(resource: String, ofType type: String = "svg", inDirectory directory: String?, fromBundle bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main) throws -> Node`

`parse(fullPath: String) throws -> Node`

`parse(text: String) throws -> Node`